# npm 4.2 install error in fresh laravel installation 5.6

Tags: laravel, npm

```
npm ERR! Error
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:29:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:114:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\wamp64\www\blog\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-330971f9' -> 'C:\wamp64\www\blog\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR!  Error
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:29:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:114:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\wamp64\www\blog\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-330971f9' -> 'C:\wamp64\www\blog\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gherr_000\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-16T22_35_31_584Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

AS the output of the command states you should try running again as an administrator as it appears the files npm is trying to edit are owned by a user other than yourself.

On Windows you can do this by running the command from git bash/CMD/powershell etc. by starting them with administrator privilege - to do so search for the program in your start menu and right click it and choose 'Run as Administrator'.